# JS does not work if selected changed

Tags: jquery, laravel

the function of JS is, when select option "1" or "3" input field2(star2) must bigger than input field1(star1), and when select option "2" or "3" input field2(star2) must smaller than input field1(star1).
JS does not work if select first time, and when change to another select, currentVal value is first select, the only way is refresh page, how JS work witout refresh page

**My Blade**

```
      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="type">Type</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control select input-sm name="type" id="type">
                  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Type Scoring Rule</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
              </div>
        </div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
   <input type="text" name="star1" id="start1" class="col-sm-5 form-control input-sm">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <input type="text" name="star2" id="start2" class="col-sm-5 form-control input-sm">
</div>
```

**My JS**

```
document.getElementById("type").onchange = function() {
var currentVal = this.value;
  if ((currentVal === "1") || (currentVal === "3")){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#start2").change(function() {
        var start2Value=$(this).val();
        var start1Value=$("#start1").val();
        if (start2Value <= start1Value)
          alert("An invalid value, input must be hihger than"+" "+ start2Value+" your select is "+currentVal);
      });
    });
  }
  else if ((currentVal === "2") || (currentVal === "4")){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#start2").change(function() {
        var start2Value=$(this).val();
        var start1Value=$("#start1").val();
        if (start2Value >= start1Value)
          alert("An invalid value, input must be smaller than"+" "+ start2Value+" your select is "+currentVal);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: description is not very clear. kindly clarify what is the requirements

Comment: how fix my JS, when first time select(type) = "1/2/3/4" and i input field star1 dan star2, its fine no problems, but when i change my select(type)  JS doesnt work. currentVal  does not change value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed both jquery and javascript select any one that is the best practice [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/12954/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#type', function(){
 var vall = $(this).val();
if( vall == 1 || vall == 3){
    var start2Value=$("#start2").val();
var start1Value=$("#start1").val();
if (start2Value <= start1Value)
      alert("An invalid value, input must be hihger than"+" "+ 
  start2Value+" your select is "+vall);
}
   else if ((vall === "2") || (vall === "4")){
   var start2Value=$("#start2").val();
     var start1Value=$("#start1").val();
if (start2Value >= start1Value)
      alert("An invalid value, input must be smaller than"+" "+ 
start2Value+" your select is "+vall);
}
 });


  $("#start2").change(function() {
   var vall = $("#type").val();
     if( vall == 1 || vall == 3){
    var start2Value=$(this).val();
    var start1Value=$("#start1").val();
    if (start2Value <= start1Value)
      alert("An invalid value, input must be hihger than"+" "+ start2Value+" your select is "+vall);
    }
          else if ((vall == 2) || (vall == 4)){
var start2Value=$(this).val();
    var start1Value=$("#start1").val();
    if (start2Value >= start1Value)
      alert("An invalid value, input must be smaller than"+" "+ start2Value+" your select is "+vall);
        }
  });
  });
```

Comment: but, why alert always pop up when select option, pop up must show after input second field

Comment: i find my solution just delete
 $(document).on('change', '#type', function(){
.....
 });